# Why does my Thread2 slow down my Thread1, while doing image loading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, io

Hope you can help me :)

**Background:**

I'm creating a relatively basic image viewer application in C# with some specific features.

One goal is for it to load relatively large images (~8mb, only .jpg really) fast enough to give a lagfree browsing experience (flipping through the images with left and right arrow key).

**My solution:**

To achieve this i have created a BufferManager class with a circulair buffer. The class which has a method MaintainBuffer which is an infinite loop that keeps the buffer filled. 
It simply checks if there is a minimum of K images in the buffer on both the left and right side of the currently viewed image, if not it loads images into the buffer until it there is. 
Now i naturally call this MaintainBuffer method on a new Thread, so that the user can flip through images without noticing the BufferManager doing work in the background and so the application can simply show users images from the buffer.

**The problem with my solution:**

My problem is that the loading of images by Thread2 into the buffer is slowing down my Thread1 (main thread), so that every time the user flips to a new image there is a small lagspike while a new image is being loaded into the buffer.

**My attempts at debugging:**

I checked my Task Manager to ensure that the threads werent executed on the same core or something wierd like that, but i can see two obvious spikes in usage on two distinct cores.
The two threads share some memory, among those are the buffer so i thought that maybe that was the issue and tried using temporary variables and only moving references into the buffer, which did not help (optimizations maybe?).

Now i read something that vaguely hinted that IO operations would slow down all my threads, however that doesnt make too much sense to me as the CPU shouldnt really be involved in moving the files into main memory and only Thread2 should be waiting for the IO operation to finish.

**My questions:**

- Am I wrong in the assumption that only Thread2 should be slowed by its IO operations?
- Could the problem be my data sharing between the threads? if so, how could I resolve it?
- What else could be causing my trouble? am i missing something fundemental in my understanding of multithreading?
- Could there even be a better solution than what im trying to do?

**The code:**

Calling of the thread in my Form1 class:

```
private void browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is just getting the image and other file filenames (others needed for a feature)
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        imageSets = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        List<string> associatedFiles;
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
            string filenameExt = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f);

            if (imageSets.ContainsKey(filename))
            {
                imageSets.TryGetValue(filename, out associatedFiles);  
                associatedFiles.Add(filenameExt); 
            }
            else
            {
                imageSets.Add(filename, new List<string>(){filenameExt});
            }
        }

        //Getting only the names of the images
        images = imageSets.Keys.ToList<string>();

        //Creating a new bufferManager, note that the 'images' list is used by the object for getting the names of the images to load
        bufferManager = new BufferManager(ref images, path);

        //Have the bufferManager load the first image and put it in the buffer
        currentImage = bufferManager.Init();

        //Create a thread for maintaining the buffer
        bufferThread = new Thread(bufferManager.MaintainBuffer);

        bufferThread.Start();

        //Display the intial image to the user
        img_preview.BackgroundImage = currentImage;
    }
```

Init method of the BufferManager:

```
public Image Init()
    {
        currentIndex = lastBufferIndex = firstBufferIndex = 0;

        Image fullSize = ImageTool.FromFile(path + "\\" + images[0] + ".jpg");
        //Resize the image in the buffer to save memory and display faster
        imageBuffer[0] = ImageTool.Resize(fullSize, 460); //The buffer is a simple array of fixed size
        fullSize.Dispose();
        return imageBuffer[0];
    }
```

The interresting method here: MaintainBuffer which is called on Thread2

```
public void MaintainBuffer()
    {
        if (images.Count <= totalBufferSize)
        {
            //If the buffer can hold all the images without swapping images ind out, just load them all and dont worry about maintaining the buffer
            totalBufferSize = images.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < totalBufferSize; ++i)
            {
                imageBuffer[i] = ImageTool.Resize(ImageTool.FromFile(path + "\\" + images[i] + ".jpg"), 460);
            }

            return;
        }


        while (!killBuffer)
        {
                //Ensure that enough images are buffered to the left of the current image. This looks a bit advanced due to being a circulair buffer, but the idea is simple
                while (currentBufferIndex >= firstBufferIndex ? (currentBufferIndex - firstBufferIndex) < bufferWidth : (currentBufferIndex + totalBufferSize - firstBufferIndex) < bufferWidth)
                {
                    --firstBufferIndex;
                    if (firstBufferIndex < 0)
                        firstBufferIndex = totalBufferSize - 1;

                    if (imageBuffer[firstBufferIndex] != null)
                        imageBuffer[firstBufferIndex].Dispose();    //Release the memory used by the image that is now "overwritten"

                    //Getting the image index of the image to load next
                    int imageNameIndex = currentIndex - (currentBufferIndex >= firstBufferIndex ? currentBufferIndex - firstBufferIndex : currentBufferIndex + totalBufferSize - firstBufferIndex);
                    if (imageNameIndex < 0)
                        imageNameIndex = images.Count + imageNameIndex;

                    Image fullSize = ImageTool.FromFile(path + "\\" + images[imageNameIndex] + ".jpg");
                    imageBuffer[firstBufferIndex] = ImageTool.Resize(fullSize, 460);
                     fullSize.Dispose();
                }

                //Ensure that enough images are buffered to the right of the current image
                while (currentBufferIndex <= lastBufferIndex ? (lastBufferIndex - currentBufferIndex) < bufferWidth : (lastBufferIndex + totalBufferSize - currentBufferIndex) < bufferWidth)
                {
                    ++lastBufferIndex;
                    if (lastBufferIndex > totalBufferSize - 1)
                        lastBufferIndex = 0;

                    if (imageBuffer[lastBufferIndex] != null)
                        imageBuffer[lastBufferIndex].Dispose();

                    int imageNameIndex = (currentIndex + (currentBufferIndex <= lastBufferIndex ? lastBufferIndex - currentBufferIndex : lastBufferIndex + totalBufferSize - currentBufferIndex)) % (images.Count);


                    Image fullSize = ImageTool.FromFile(path + "\\" + images[imageNameIndex] + ".jpg");
                    imageBuffer[lastBufferIndex] = ImageTool.Resize(fullSize, 460);
                   fullSize.Dispose();
                }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }
```

I omitted code for flipping images left and right as it's pretty simple. It does however update the currentIndex (index of the image being viewed atm) and currentBufferIndex (the current images position in the circulair buffer) of the BufferManager object on Thread1 which is an example of data sharing that could be causing a problem maybe?

I'm not too experienced with multithreading as you probably noticed, so i hope you'll be able to give me some pointers! Thanks

Comment: I'm interested to hear why you think the CPU isn't involved in moving memory around? You should, for starters, begin looking into the `Interlocked` class for changing the values of some of these integers. You've mentioned they are edited from either thread.. yet I see no use of `lock`'s or anything. Also, the Task Parallel Library gives you some simple syntax for complex threading solutions, have a look into that as well.

Comment: Why are you using Thread.Sleep(100) why not use a `ManualResetEvent` to signal when you want it to repeat?

Comment: @Simon I'll look into Interlocked and that library. Regarding locking i was kind of just waiting to see if i got some race conditions before getting to that part. But do you think the library or Interlocked class can help me with my performance issue?

- ---- CodeCamper I haven't heard that term before, but a sleep seemed like a much simpler solution to keep the thread from busywaiting too much than using an event based solution.

Comment: @JacobJensen: The lack of proper synchronization renders your code basically unanalyzable. Perhaps one thread is slowing down the other because they're stomping all over each other.

Comment: Like @CodeCamper suggests, get rid of the latency-adding, CPU-wasting Sleep() loop first and use proper inter-thread signaling.

Comment: @MartinJames Are you telling me that Sleep is implemented as busywait in C#? And i'll be trying out the Task Parallel Library and see if that helps with my thread correlation. From what i am reading on the library, it suggests that i can just my shared data without worry, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: 'Sleep is implemented as busywait in C#' - no. What I'm saying is that Sleep(100) will introduce an average 50ms latency to the detection of those index tests and that those checks will run every 100ms even if they are destined to fail - something that can be avoided with signaling.

Comment: Ah yes i see what you mean. but all this is besides the point. All i want is to understand why my threads are lagging eachother, been trying to use some concurrent datastructures last couple of hours, but they dont seem to fit my needs nor help the lagging.